# How to update only one property in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose

This is my model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const UserData = new mongoose.Schema({
    additionalData: Array,
    name: String,
});
mongoose.model('UserData', UserDataSchema);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

export default mongoose.model('UserData');
```

How can I update `additionalData` property of `UserData` model so for example another array is appended.

Let's say additional array is

`[ 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

```
await UserData.update({name:"something"},{ $addToSet: { additionalData: [1,2,3] })
```

or

```
await UserData.updateOne({name:"something"},{ $addToSet: { additionalData: [1,2,3] })
```

If you have no condition do this ,this will add to all documents

```
await UserData.update({},{ $addToSet: { additionalData: [1,2,3] })
```

If you want to remove multiple values from the array,use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
await UserData.update({},{ $pull: { additionalData: { $in: [ 1, 2,3 ] }}})
```

If you wish to remove single value

```
await UserData.update({},{ $pull: { additionalData:1 }})
```

Comment: But why do I need `name`, I am trying to make the migration, so this is always populated?

Comment: But you need some condition right?? ,update where (in sql terms)

Comment: That seems to work great, thanks. What is the opposite of this, since I need the migrate-down option as well?

Comment: I mean you want to remove ?? a value from array?

Comment: What is the remove, or revert as it was before?

Comment: Nice. Can you empty an array so `additionalData = []` ?

Comment: `await UserData.update({},{ $set: { additionalData:[] }})` this will do. Se set -https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Answer (score 1):

If this is not what you mean, let me know in the comments, I'll edit the answer.

```
const newArray = [ 1, 2, 3];
const nameToUpdate = 'foo';
mongoose.model('UserData').updateMany({
    name: nameToUpdate
}, {$set: {
    additionalData: newArray
}});
```

Comment: Should we use `updateMany()` or `updateOne()`, since this is only one property?

Comment: `updateOne` doesn't mean that you will update only one property. It means that you will update only one _document_ . Your schema has multiple documents which have multiple properties. If you want to update many documents with one query (e.g. every document that has a name "foo"), you should use `updateMany`. On the other hand, if you want to make sure that your query will update only one document and no matter how many properties, you should use `updateOne`.